# Azure Devops -Test Data displayed in pipeline is incorrect and is displaying data which i ran in my local esktop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, test-plan

I needed a small help. Whenever I run the pipeline, the data being displayed in testtab is incorrect and it displays the data which I ran on my local desktop rather than the job ran on Agent.

Answer (score 0):

- *You can run tests in test tabs using different options. You can use any to solve your problem:*

1. *Automatically inferred test result:  for some popular test runners' pipeline automatically infer the test output.*

*This is done with the help of describing the error logs generated during build operation.*

2. *Publish Test result task: Publishes test result to azure pipeline you choose the runner for tests execution available in
   any formats.*
3. *Test execution tasks: Built -in test execution tasks such as visual studio test that automatically publish tests results to the pipeline*

- *Azure Devops also provide other way to surface the test information You can use this.*

1. *Test analytics provide rich insights into test result over a period of time, identify problematic area in your test.*
2. *The dashboard provide track of your work's progress add widgets that surface test related information.*

   - Requirement quality
   - Test result trend
   - Deployment status

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops